# Different outputs from two different syntax that should produce the same output

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

A node `A` will be constructed by using 2 syntax.

- `\pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){A}`
- `\pnode[3,2](!2 3 0 p2c){A}`

Each constructs the node `A` by translating a point `(!2 3 0 p2c)` (which is on an *basic* ellipse) 3 unit rightward and 2 unit upward.

### First Syntax

```
\pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){A}
```

And the output is as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pstVerb{/p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def}% b a t p2c --> x y
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,4)
    \pnode(3,2){center}
    \pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){A}
    \pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){B}
    \pscustom[origin={center},fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan]
    {
        \psellipticarc(center)(3,2){(A)}{(B)}
        \lineto(center)
        \closepath
    }   
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Second Syntax

```
\pnode[3,2](!2 3 0 p2c){A}
```

And the output is as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pstVerb{/p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def}% b a t p2c --> x y
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,4)
    \pnode(3,2){center}
    \pnode[3,2](!2 3 0 p2c){A}
    \pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){B}
    \pscustom[origin={center},fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan]
    {
        \psellipticarc(center)(3,2){(A)}{(B)}
        \lineto(center)
        \closepath
    }   
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Why are the outputs different?

### Edit:

I noticed that the problem will be fixed only if both `A` and `B` are expressed in the same syntax, either

```
    \pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){A}
    \pnode(!2 3 0 p2c exch 3 add exch 2 add){B}
```

or

```
    \pnode[3,2](!2 3 0 p2c){A}
    \pnode[3,2](!2 3 0 p2c){B}
```

But I still don't understand why the output is different for the given examples above (before the Edit section)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first example I get the x/y values of A/B:

```
2.00000048
6.00000048
2.0
5.99999952
```

and for the second

```
2.0
5.99999952
2.0
5.99999952
```

Comment: +1: Is there a way to globally round any PS calculation to six digits after decimal point?

Comment: not with a simple command